# How to configure size of shared-cache in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, caching, shared-cache

SQLite provide a shared-cache mode (https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) which will help to reduce cache size among multiple connections within a process. But how to configure the size of the shared cache? I've tried `PRAGMA cache_size = 536870912`. But no matter how much space i offered, it seems to have no effect on memory consumption. So is there's a configuration to set the size of shared-cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not special shared cache; the shared-cache mode just shared the normal cache.
This cache can be configured with `PRAGMA cache_size`.

With the default page size of 4 KB, a cache size of 536870912 pages would result in a limit of 2 TB. It is unlikely that you have reached that.